# JTable not showing in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel

I'm having a problem with displaying a `JTable` in a `JPanel`. I'm having the user press a button and within this button the table should generate the table and put in an already existing panel, now when I tried to open it in a new `JFrame` the data shows perfectly but I want to show it in a `JPanel`.

Code:

```
   files = c.RequestFile("list"); //gets the data of files
        Object[][] filesArray = new Object[files.size()][1];
        int size = 0;
        for (FileInfo fileInfo : files) {
            filesArray[size][0] = fileInfo.getName();
            size++;
        }

        fileTablePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        fileTablePanel.add(new JScrollPane(createTable(filesArray)));
```

Comment: For many components in one space, use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as seen in this [short example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).  But the typical approach with a `JTable` is to add it at start up, and *populate it* (add data) when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the new content to the panel, you need to repaint the panel to the screen:

```
fileTablePanel.revalidate();
fileTablePanel.repaint();
```

It works when you popup a new JFrame since it's the first time the JFrame is painted to the screen.

Comment: *"that is what i needed"*  That is the right answer to the wrong question.  See the post of peeskillet for the correct approach.

Comment: No, this is the right answer @AndrewThompson. The problem is when he updates his panel, the table is not showing, but it is showing when he creates a new JFrame instead, this is because he isn't repainting his panel. Even if he uses a TableModel, he'll still need to repaint after changing the table

Comment: *"Even if he uses a TableModel, he'll still need to repaint after changing the table"*  You completely missed the point.  There should only be one table and one model.  Change the data in the model, and the view changes.  Look ma, no hands (and no p*ssing about with adding and removing components)!

Comment: I'm not saying that using a TableModel is wrong, it is the better way to go, but it doesn't solve the problem. Repainting the panel solves it.

Comment: *"but it doesn't solve the problem."*  Hence 'wrong question'..  You really should pay more attention.  -1 as a warning to future visitors that this entire ***question*** is off the mark.

Answer (score 4):

You want to look into using a `TableModel`. What you are currently doing is trying to replace one `JTable` with another `JTable`. That is totally unnecessary. You should just manipulate the data of the `TableModel`.

You can see more at [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). You can focus on the section [Creating a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

Answer (score 0):

You need to repaint the table like this

```
fileTablePanel.repaint();
```